# How to get the version number of the latest stable release of Python via single HTTP request?

Tags: python

I'm working on a script that needs to download the latest binary version of the Python interpreter from the python.org website.

How do I get the version number of the latest stable release of Python?

Unfortunately, the CPython repository on Github is not using Releases, so I can't get the latest version via releases/latest, and the only option I currently see is parsing the python.org website, which isn't a good one since it depends on the future python.org redesigns.

I'd like to be able to get the version number via a single HTTP request if it's possible.

Comment: [The python.org's ftp page](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/) lists all the versions. You can get the latest version and the corresponding executables by processing the parsed HTML list with regex and sorting. I wasn't sure if that's the approach you decided against, earlier.

Comment: @Nope. Thanks! It looks like the best option for now, though I still hope there are some simpler ways to do it. Also, their ftp page is listing the development versions as well, so getting the latest stable one will require even more parsing.

Comment: @mew: You can't actually. For instance as of Feb 7 2024 `3.13.0` is the latest version in that ftp page, but that's a development version and the latest stable version is `3.12.12` according to [The Python hompage](https://www.python.org/) which was just released on Feb. 6, 2024.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although a bit hacky, I found that the website https://endoflife.date/python has the list of stable releases (along with its end of life dates) and it also provides an API for it.

Reading the documentation for the API given here https://endoflife.date/docs/api/, it looks like the first element of the json list is always the latest stable version. Therefore you can get the latest stable version string by using

```
import requests
result = requests.get("https://endoflife.date/api/python.json")
parsed_result = result.json()
version_string =  parsed_result[0]["latest"]
```

Note that they've mentioned that the API is currently in Alpha.

Comment: Seems like the best solution so far, thank you!

Comment: That's pretty nice but it's a little bit laggy. For instance it lists `3.12.1 (07 Dec 2023)` as the latest rather than `3.12.2` which was just released today or yesterday.